# In this sentence, should I say faces/figures/persons/personages or some other word?

Tags: word-choice

During a retrospect of how the EU has accommodated to financial adversities since 2008, a commentator says that *"in terms of _______, nothing has changed"*, implying that those in charge, at least when it comes to financial matters, have pretty much remained the same.

My first thought was ***"faces"***, but my uncertainty eventually prevailed.

Now I'm thinking ***"figures"***, perhaps, as in *"public figure"*, ***"persons"***, as in, say, the legal definition of a *"natural person"*, or ***"personages"*** (which sounds quite nice, though I've never really used it...)

?

Comment: "in terms of leadership". I would use this term.

Comment: @Rathony Hmm... he's mostly referring to technocratic positions (finance ministers at most), however, not such evident "leaders" as presidents, prime ministers and the like...

Comment: If I was looking for a general way to refer to a group of people in an organisation, I would use *personnel*.